# Click once Deployment suddenly does not work. Displays windows login?

Tags: winforms, clickonce

I am facing a peculiar issue. We use click once deployment for our windows application. It was working fine till last week. I made some changes to the application (just code nothing changed in properties) and suddenly I cannot publish anymore. When we give publish now it displays windows authentication dialog and when we provide the credentials nothing happens. It tries to connect to remote server (local LAN) and shows the dialog again.

Any idea why this happens?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you publishing it to http or ftp? Have they added password-protection to the server so you have to enter credentials in order to publish the application?

After you enter credentials, what does it say in the Output window?

Comment: Sorry for the late reply Robin. I am using http and my network administrators informed me that they didn't touch that server. The last entry in the output window is :"Creating folder 'Application Files/QualityReview_2_0_0_103' in Web site http://....." but stops right there. Thanks for your help.

Comment: I just came to know that it was indeed a permission issue. One of my developers was trying a deployment script (batch file) and he was messing with the file permissions. Thank you so much :-)